# How to keep UIView at relative distance from other after resizing?

Tags: objective-c

I have five `UIView` on a `UIScrollView`. All of them with the same width. Each view has other subviews that resize its height according to the content assigned, thus making the parent UIView and the `UIScrollView` resizable as well. I am trying to keep the 5 `UIView` separated from each other at a certain "Padding" distance even after resizing. What I do right now is set the position of the origin.y and the height of each `UIView` when `layoutSubviews` is called. Is there an easier way to do this?
I have tried to set their position on creation like: `CGRectMake(0, aboveView.frame.origin.y + aboveView.frame.size.height + Padding, width, 0)` and setting its `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingMaskTopMargin`. Hoping that when I call `sizeToFit` on the main `UIView`, all the `UView` will set their positions relative to the view above them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding `layoutSubviews` is the right way to do this.  UIKit doesn't have any built-in layout management that can do it for you.

However, you might not realize that `UIScrollView` sends itself `layoutSubviews` each time it scrolls - on every frame of the scrolling.  That may be a lot more often than you need!  You don't want to do a lot of work in a `UIScrollView`'s `layoutSubviews` if you can avoid it.

To avoid doing extra layout, I suggest you set up your view hierarchy like this:

```
UIScrollView
    ContainerView with layoutSubviews method
        content view 1
        content view 2
        content view 3
        content view 4
        content view 5
```

Use a standard `UIScrollView`.  Give it one subview, which is a custom `UIView` subclass (I called it `ContainerView` in my example).  The `ContainerView` has your five content views as its subviews.

When you assign new content to one of your five content views, send `sizeToFit` to that content view.  If the view's size changes, UIKit should automatically send `layoutSubviews` to its superview - the `ContainerView`.  The `ContainerView`'s `layoutSubviews` method adjusts the position of its subviews to maintain the padding between them, and then sets the `contentSize` of its parent - the `UIScrollView`.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        CGRect frame = subview.frame;
        if (myFrame.size.height > 0) {
            frame.origin.y = myBounds.size.height + Padding;
            subview.frame = frame;
        }
        myFrame = CGRectUnion(myFrame, frame);
    }
    self.frame = myFrame;
    UIScrollView *scrollView = self.superview;
    scrollView.contentSize = myFrame.size;
}
```

This way, you don't do any extra work just because the scroll view scrolled.  You only lay out your content views when the content actually changes.

Comment: this is the way I am doing it. Thanks for making it clear. It just seems to me that it is a lot of extra code for something that should be easier.